# Display info dialog in the Google Static Maps API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2, google-maps-static-api

Nowhere in the [Google Static Maps API](http://code.google.com/intl/es-ES/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/) it's mentioned the use of the dialog boxes. Are they possible to show on a static map?

[image: dialog in google static map]

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?